# What must i do with script, generated by EDM model?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, ef-model-first

I am writing a test app, using Entity Framework with model-first approach. I had created an EDM model with tables, than created a SQL Server CE database, created connection to db and than Master created a file *.edmx.sqlce with big sql script. What i must do next? How to use it?

Comment: You could use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in to execute it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the script against the database which will create the database for your model. There should be a "Play" icon in the toolbar (similar to a "Play" button on old cassete players) you can click to execute the script.